# UIAlertView on iOS 7 Doesn't Display the title

Tags: ios, ios7, uialertview

So I am neck deep in a project, and we kept running into this problem in multiple places throughout it.  When we display a UIAlertView the standard, typical way, the title doesn't display on the alert, only the description and buttons.  We do the initialization and display as anyone would:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Are you sure?" message:@"Deleting a ..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Delete" otherButtonTitles:@"Cancel", nil];
[alert show];
```

Has anyone else ever run into this problem? We aren't importing and dependency that changes anything with that, nor are we doing anything that we can tell would cause this.

Edit: Here's an example of what I'm seeing:
[image]

Comment: something not shown here is going wrong. this code is fine and will show the title. are you doing something else to format the alert?

Comment: Remove the comma after @"Hello"

Comment: What's with the `,` after `@"Hello"`? I assume that's a typo. Other then that there is nothing wrong with this and should work what else are you doing?

Comment: Try to delete the comma after cancelButtonTitle:@"Hello"

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo on my part.

Comment: can you post a screenshot of how it looks?

Comment: Well your bug is that, that screenshot doesn't match up with the code. Please share correct code.

Comment: There ya go, exact code, I just ellipsified the detail text.

Comment: Are you using a framework or class that modifies UIAlertView with a category or other alteration?

Comment: Using cocoapods: 
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0.1'
pod 'GCNetworkReachability', '~> 1.3.0'
pod 'MagicalRecord', '~> 2.2'
pod 'FXKeychain', '~> 1.4'

pod 'CocoaLumberjack', '~> 1.6.2'

pod 'TestFlightSDK', '~> 2.0'
pod 'TestFlightLogger', '~> 0.0.3'

Comment: I just tried that code and there are is at least one more detail that is wrong with your alert. The Cancel button should use a slightly bolder font. If you change the message in code, does the alert change as well? Just want to make sure that you are actually looking at the code that shows the alert. Many times I have looked at code that did not match the results on screen, just to figure out later that this code was part of old leftover classes that were no longer in use. And I would try to use NSStrings of different length for the message, maybe you really hit a render bug in UIAlertView

Comment: I'm only ever showing 3 different alert views in the entire app - and I'm only doing it like so.  This is the exact code I'm calling, minus the truncated text.  I'm really stumped on this one - the code is cut and dry, and something outside of that has to be effecting it.  I guess I was mainly curious to see if anyone has run into this kind of thing before.  I'm going to start knocking out my dependencies one by one to see if anything changes.  That's the only thing I can think of to do.  I have done a search for occurrences of UIAlertView, and that has come up empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also met the same problem. The root cause is that I used "UIFont+Replacement" in my project.  In iOS 7, system will use "UIFont fontWithDescriptor:" to setup font for labels in system controls.

I added a judgment to check whether the font replacement is used for system controls like UIAlertView. Please check my code, so far it works well:

```
UIFontDescriptor *replaceDescriptor = descriptor;
if (![descriptor.fontAttributes objectForKey@"NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute"] 
|| ![((NSString *)[descriptor.fontAttributes objectForKey:@"NSCTFontUIUsageAttribute"])     
isEqualToString:@"UICTFontUsageEmphasizeBody"]) 
{
NSString *replacementFontName = [replacementDictionary objectForKey:descriptor.postscriptName];
replaceDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithName:replacementFontName size:pointSize];
}
return [self replacement_fontWithDescriptor:replaceDescriptor size:pointSize];
```

Comment: Thanks! We are using that too!

Comment: Did you end up not using that? Or did you modify it to do something? I tried this fix: https://github.com/0xced/FontReplacer/pull/6